# JSF 2.3 on open liberty. Immediate javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3, open-liberty

I am experimenting with Open Liberty and wanted to try out JSF-2.3 support. I must be doing something silly because when trying implicit navigation I immediately get the exception:

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View "/view/index.xhtml" could not be restored.
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:181)
```

I can render an initial Facelets-page using the following server.xml features:

```
 <featureManager>
        <feature>servlet-4.0</feature>
        <feature>jsf-2.3</feature>
        <feature>el-3.0</feature>
        <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

My page is really simple and looks like this:

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="It works!"/>
    <br/>

    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink value="NAvigate"  action="view/page2" />
        <h:commandButton value="NAvigate 2"  action="view/page2" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

I have a corresponding `page2.xhtml`.

When clicking on either the commandLink or commandButton I get the exception:

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View "/view/index.xhtml" could not be restored.
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:181)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:195)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:142)
```

Have I mis-configured something in Open Liberty or are my JSF-mojo just lacking severely?

Comment: what was your old jsf version? And do you have a cluster? And client-side state-saving or not?

Comment: No cluster. There is no old version, this is a completely new WAR where I test JSF 2.3 in open liberty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh.. after testing in another browser (Safari) it worked. Hard-resetting Chrome site storage then fixed the original problem.

This problem must have surfaced somewhere in between automatic restarts.